# How to run `prisma generate` in production?

Tags: node.js, prisma, prisma2

I'm confused about how Prisma code generation in production works. The Prisma CLI is supposed to be installed in devDependencies, yet the `npx prisma generate` command needs to be available in production, since the generated code is necessary for the application. How can I resolve this? I tried running `npm i --production` and `npx prisma generate`, which led to the expected problem of npx trying to auto-install prisma and getting Prisma 1 instead of Prisma 2 and then expecting a prisma.yml file which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to run the `prisma generate` command that is executed on installation of the `@prisma/client`.

EDIT:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/generating-prisma-client

Comment: But running the `prisma generate` command, done automatically or manually, would require the Prisma CLI to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

That's what I did in package.json file (It was a deploy a Next app on Versel) I just added generate command to the build script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Not sure if it is a correct way, though..

Answer (score 0):

Prisma has various guides for installing on different environments.
For example, this one talks about installing on vercel.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-vercel

> Postinstall hook
> The package.json uses the postinstall hook script to run prisma generate. Typically this would go in the build step. Because Vercel caches node_modules after the dependencies are installed, the functions won't have access to the generated Prisma Client.

> Generating the Prisma Client in postinstall ensures that the generated Prisma Client in node_modules/@prisma/client is available to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Prisma package has a postinstall hook. From [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/setup-and-configuration/generating-prisma-client#generating-prisma-client-in-the-postinstall-hook-of-prismaclient):

> The @prisma/client package defines its own postinstall hook that's being executed whenever the package is being installed. This hook invokes the prisma generate command which in turn generates the Prisma Client code into the default location node_modules/.prisma/client. Notice that this requires the prisma CLI to be available, either as local dependency or as a global installation. It is recommended to always install the prisma package as a development dependency, using npm install prisma --save-dev, to avoid versioning conflicts.

If you're deploying to Vercel you should know that Vercel caches the node_modules dependencies, so the [Prisma docs have workarounds](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/help-and-troubleshooting/help-articles/vercel-caching-issue).

The **tl;dr** is if you're using Vercel for production add this to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`:

```json
scripts: {
   // ... your other scripts
   "postinstall": "npx prisma generate",
}
```